# Using 404 page as redirect system?

Tags: php, redirect, seo

I have to move a entire site to a new domain, the old domain will be used for another site, so I wish delete all files in old domain. 
Can I delete all file and use 404 error page to redirect traffic to new pages?

example:

```
if($page == "http://www.site1.com/pagexxx.htm") {
   header( 'Location: http://www.site2.com/new_page.html' ) ;
}
```

It technically and SEO correct?

Comment: Is it an option to redirect already at an earlier stage, e.g. at the webserver level? I would prefer to redirect at webserver level (e.g. Apache redirect statements) instead of doing this at application level.

Comment: You're better off doing this using `.htaccess`

Comment: There are thousand files, it's not a problem for .htaccess?

Comment: Not if you code it right, no it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Redirect the whole site using .htaccess to the new site.

Comment: it is better to redirect everything with 301 status (be patient, that 404 or other statuses will not work correct for google and others). easier way to use .htaccess. try this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mynewsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]` it will be the best decision technically and seo way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method is to create another php file on your old domain, and in `.htaccess` add the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /dir/.../file.php
```

You just need to get the request uri in php and process the url and use the `header` function to redirect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing 1:1 redirection, then just setup a redirect rule on your web server.

If, instead, you want to inform users that the site as moved, and redirect everything to the front page of the new site, I'd do the following:

1.) Create a redirect/rewrite rule on the web server to direct everything to your "This site has moved" page. I'd prefer a rewrite, so that they can easily change existing bookmarks.

2.) Put a message informing them of the move, a link to the new site, and a meta-refresh to automatically redirect after 5-10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would try it in `.htaccess` create or update an `.htaccess` file and put it in the root of the old domain with this below. If you are just changing domain names and files locations are still the same, this will redirect all traffic from old to new.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```